# Firebase, can't increase value of child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and I have work for 6 months to get all I need to go ahead to start building my own apps but I was having a problem that I couldn't make a button that every time I click it increase the value of child, EX: When I click the value will be 0 the I click another click the value should be 1 and so on but I couldn't do that I have used these method's below but nothing work so I have to ask now to get the simple answer for my question.

The First Method:

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Long Value = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("Rank").getValue();
            mDatabase.child("Rank").setValue(Value+1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And the second:

`mDatabase.child("Rank").setValue(+1);`

But all these doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I had such an issue and noted that if the write permissions are not well set in the database settings it might lead to such a problem. Please check the permissions and tell me if this works

Comment: Nope it doesn't work brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are talking about increasing a value i recomand you using transactions like this:

```
mDatabase.child("Rank").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
    if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
        currentData.setValue("0");
    } else {
        String stringValue = (String) currentData.getValue();
        int intValue = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
        int increasedIntValue = intValue + 1;
        currentData.setValue(String.valueOf(increasedIntValue));
    }
        return Transaction.success(currentData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Firebase counter increment failed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Firebase counter increment succeeded!");
        }
    }
});
```

Another approch, as 7uthaifah mentioned later is this:

```
mDatabaseMostActive.child("Rank").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Long Num =(Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Long NumAfter = Num+1;
    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(NumAfter);}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

Hope it helps and future visitos will understand better this ways of solving the problem.

Comment: Sorry brother it doesn't work it always give me -1 value only

Comment: If you get -1, your `DatabaseReference` might be wrong. Can post your database structure?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly thanks for Alex Mamo for answering the question and the answer was perfect but I find a better way by using "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" method here's my fully method:

```
mDatabaseMostActive.child("Rank").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    Long Num =(Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                    Long NumAfter = Num+1;
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(NumAfter);}
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

hope it helps.